# How to pack laravel request with my own variables in middleware for later use?

Tags: php, laravel

I found that I can do like

`$request->merge(['aplika' => 5]);`

or

`$request->request->add(['aplika' => 5]);`

But it goes to Request + Query in this Request.

And there can be later problem when working with model or request form.

I found I can do other way and put it in attributes like:

`$request->attributes->add(['aplika' => 5]);`

And it goes to attributes

[image: image showing this]

But how to later read this in controller?

How to get this?

Maybe there is other way in I can pack my request in middleware in some variables not used to validation / model things but other purpose?